# Multiple fields in an IN clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to include multiple fields in an IN clause? Something like the following?

```
select * from data
where id1, id2 in (select id from dataset)
```

I would like the query to return those cases in data in which the id1 and/or id2 fields appear in the id field in dataset.

I am using postgresql.

Comment: Not the way it looks like you want it to mean. I think what you mean is `... Where id1 in (select id from...) And id2 in (select I'd from...)`. Is that indeed so?

Comment: Please explain the logic you want here.

Comment: @Mischa Yes, is there a way to shorten it? My real data contain 5 id fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about converting it into `JOIN` since such function you are looking does not exist?

```
select a.* 
from data a INNER JOIN dataset b
    ON a.id1 = b.id OR a.id2 = b.id
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
select  * 
from    data
where   exists (select  id 
                from    dataset 
                where   id = id1
                    OR  id = id2
                    ...
                    OR  id = id5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have five ids and you know they are distinct, you can do.  `select ... from data where 5=(select count(*) from dataset where id in (id1, id2, ... id5))`